# How do I show my global Git configuration?

Tags: git

I'd like to show all configured Git sections.

I only found `git config --get core.editor`, and I'd like to output everything that's configured globally, not only the configured default editor.

Comment: What's wrong with looking at .gitconfig?

Comment: Note that you will soon (Q3/Q4 2015) have with git 2.6 the option `--name-only`, to list only the config keys, without their values. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32325189/6309)

Comment: `$ git config --list` [Checking-Your-Settings](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup#Checking-Your-Settings)

Comment: It should be `git config --global --list` as explained deeper in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56506187/5884955)

Answer (score 2574, accepted):

You can use:

```sh
git config --list
```

or look at your `~/.gitconfig` file. The local configuration will be in your repository's `.git/config` file.

Use:

```sh
git config --list --show-origin
```

to see where that setting is defined (global, user, repo, etc...)

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted you both. I wanted to know the `git config --list` command because I can look at the effective config in a repository and I can differ local, global and system config with the appropriate parameter (`--global`, `--local`, `--system`). I'll accept your answer as soon as I'm able to because you were a few seconds faster :)

Comment: Be careful, there are a lot of potential sources for git configuration. Looking at the file gives only a part. @linquize's answer is in fact correct.

Comment: @vonbrand: --list is equivalent to -l.

Comment: Shorthands (like `-l`) come in handy when you become a power user and use the feature often enough, to actually profit from typing less characters. I find it easier to find and remember the long `--list` option. For less obvious shorthands I often have to check what do they stand for, so I prefer long names. They're even easier, with command completion, when you don't really have to type all characters, but still see whole option name.

Comment: What if `git config --list` prints nothing?

Comment: @MatejJ then maybe your `~ /.gitconfig` and `.git/config` do not have anything in them

Comment: With Git 2.34.1 on Windows, `git config --list` starts a `vi`-like editor within the command prompt for an unknown file that contains a load of settings, even though I've set Notepad++ as the editor.  Doesn't seem like that should happen.  Any ideas?  Is this a bug?

Comment: Note that If you have the same setting entry with multiple values listed, the **last** value (at the botttom) will be in use. The local setting will always override global settings.

Comment: What is .gitconfig only has a link to a credential helper? `[credential]
 helper = /mnt/c/Program\\ Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git-credential-manager-core.exe`

Answer (score 295):

The shortest,

```
git config -l
```

shows all inherited values from: system, global and local

Comment: Does this differ from _git config --list_, or is it just a shorter way to write it?

Comment: @Magnilex it's just a shorter way to write it

Comment: The config files may not always show *all* inherited configurations, but `git config -l` will show everything. Saved me because git for windows sets `autocrlf` on the installation, and it's not in any config file I can find.

Comment: yes, there is also C:\ProgramData\Git\config file - I guess this is global or system git config file

Answer (score 253):

> How do I edit my **global** Git configuration?

Short answer: `git config --edit --global`

---

To understand Git configuration, you should know that:

> ## Git configuration variables can be stored at three different levels. Each level overrides values at the previous level.

**1. System level (applied to every user on the system and all their repositories)**

- to view, `git config --list --system` (may need `sudo`)
- to set, `git config --system color.ui true`
- to edit system config file, `git config --edit --system`

**2. Global level (values specific personally to you, the user).**

- to view, `git config --list --global`
- to set, `git config --global user.name xyz`
- to edit global config file, `git config --edit --global`

**3. Repository level (specific to that single repository)**

- to view, `git config --list --local`
- to set, `git config --local core.ignorecase true` (`--local` optional)
- to edit repository config file, `git config --edit --local` (`--local` optional)

> ## How do I view **all** settings?

- Run `git config --list`, showing **system**, **global**, and (if inside a repository) **local** configs
- Run `git config --list --show-origin`, also shows the origin file of each config item

> ## How do I read one particular configuration?

- Run `git config user.name` to get `user.name`, for example.
- You may also specify options `--system`, `--global`, `--local` to read that value at a particular level.

---

Reference: *[1.6 Getting Started - First-Time Git Setup](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup)*

Comment: `git config --list` show all global, system and local? i need affirmation :)

Comment: just to add where the config files are: System: C:\ProgramData\Git\config (in windows). Global: C:\Users\user\.gitconfig  (Windows) ~/.gitconfig (Linux)   Local: project-repo/.git/config

Comment: @AdiPrasetyo Yes. You can run `git config  --list --show-origin` to find out the origin of each config item.

Comment: Every time I try the git config --global --edit command I end up in some crazy editor and after a while arguing with it I want to join some militant group to track down whom made it. So I am sorry, -1 from me.

Comment: There can be more than user specific global config file. per [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES):

`$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config
Second user-specific configuration file. If $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is not set or empty, $HOME/.config/git/config will be used.`

If you have this file and a ~/.gitconfig you can see that they are both treated as global files using:
`git config --list --show-origin --show-scope`

Answer (score 116):

```
git config --list
```

is one way to go. I usually just open up `.gitconfig` though.

Comment: Did you intend `~/.gitconfig` or one of the other files mentioned in the FILES section of `git help config`?

Comment: @chwarr - Sorry, I dont undersrtand. Did I "intend"?

Comment: I think you meant to say "I usually just open up `~/.gitconfig` though.", as git doesn't look for `.gitconfig` in the current directory, regardless of where you are. (`.gitconfig` and `~/.gitconfig` name different files [*usually*].) The other files mentioned in `git help config` have different file names, hence the assumption.

Answer (score 42):

Since Git [2.26.0](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.26.0/Documentation/RelNotes/2.26.0.txt), you can use [`--show-scope`](https://github.blog/2020-03-22-highlights-from-git-2-26/#some-new-config-tricks) option:

```
git config --list --show-scope
```

Example output:

```
system  rebase.autosquash=true
system  credential.helper=helper-selector
global  core.editor='code.cmd' --wait -n
global  merge.tool=kdiff3
local   core.symlinks=false
local   core.ignorecase=true
```

It can be combined with

- `--local` for project config,  `--global` for user config,  `--system` for all users' config
- `--show-origin` to show the exact config file location

Answer (score 39):

You can also call `git config -e` to open the configuration file in your editor directly. The Git configuration file is much more readable that the `-l` output, so I always tend to use the `-e` flag.

So to summarise:

```
git config -l  # List Git configuration settings (same as --list)
git config -e  # Opens Git configuration in the default editor (same as --edit)
```

- Without parameters it interacts with the local `.git/config`.
- With `--global` it interacts with `~/.gitconfig`.
- And with `--system` it interacts with `$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig`.

(I couldn't really find what `$(prefix)` means, but it seems to default to `$HOME`.)

Answer (score 23):

One important thing about `git config`:

`git config` has `--local`, `--global` and `--system` levels and corresponding files.

So you may use `git config --local`, `git config --global` and `git config --system`.

By default, `git config` will write to a *local* level if no configuration option is passed. Local configuration values are stored in a file that can be found in the repository's .git directory: `.git/config`

Global level configuration is user-specific, meaning it is applied to an operating system user. Global configuration values are stored in a file that is located in a user's home directory. `~/.gitconfig` on Unix systems and `C:\Users\<username>\.gitconfig` on Windows.

System-level configuration is applied across an entire machine. This covers all users on an operating system and all repositories. The system level configuration file lives in a `gitconfig` file off the system root path. $(prefix)/etc/gitconfig on Linux systems.
On Windows this file can be found in `C:\ProgramData\Git\config`.

So your option is to find that global `.gitconfig` file and edit it.

Or you can use `git config --global --list`.

This is exactly the line what you need.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to get the path to any of those files? I know you've explained where they can be found, but my question is from a different approach.

Comment: Search for something like "Where to find system, global and local Git config files" and you will get what you need. ;)

Answer (score 19):

You can also use `cat ~/.gitconfig`.

Answer (score 16):

To list your global Git config:

`git config --list --global`

To list your local git config:

`git config --list --local`

Answer (score 15):

To easily show your global Git configuration Use:

- `git config --global --list` to display list of all configurations.
- `git config --global --get user.name` shows your username.
- `git config --global --get user.email` displays your email.
- `git config --global credential.helper` verify credentials.
- `git config --global gui.recentrepo` find your recent repo.

You may need to specify where you want to read those configurations, Just add the level option:

1. `--system`: System level which applied to every user on the system and all their repositories.
2. `--global`: Global level whose values are specific personally to you, the user.
3. `--local`: Repository level has a specific to that single repository.

Comment: I always wondered why '--global' is not '--user' instead.

Answer (score 11):

Git 2.6 (Sept/Oct 2015) will add the option `--name-only` to simplify the output of a `git config -l`:

See [commit a92330d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a92330d21c13cf244d8045f5c9d1df6e63893d58), [commit f225987](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f2259877531ed2a58ec04aeaeb6beb5183f81f92), [commit 9f1429d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f1429df179adb7a315616d01c9b237b521a3733) (20 Aug 2015) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
See [commit ebca2d4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ebca2d49577665db0318a9c91c0bcca7e4eed963) (20 Aug 2015), and [commit 905f203](https://github.com/git/git/commit/905f2036d0975a828f764947384e732c2908d6eb), [commit 578625f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/578625fa918922713a2ecce2b06611e4566778f5) (10 Aug 2015) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit fc9dfda](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fc9dfda1be25ab3bb311900c6cfbf59d6b6e224e), 31 Aug 2015)</sup>

> ## `config`: add '`--name-only`' option to list only variable names
>
> '`git config`' can only show values or name-value pairs, so if a shell
>   script needs the names of set config variables it has to run '`git config --list`' or '`--get-regexp`' and parse the output to separate config variable names from their values.
>   However, such a parsing can't cope with multi-line values.
>
> Though '`git config`' can produce null-terminated output for newline-safe parsing, that's of no use in such a case, because shells can't cope with null characters.
>
> Even our own bash completion script suffers from these issues.
>
> Help the completion script, and shell scripts in general, by introducing
>   the '`--name-only`' option to modify the output of '`--list`' and
>   '`--get-regexp`' to list only the names of config variables, so they don't
>   have to perform error-prone post processing to separate variable names
>   from their values anymore.

Answer (score 8):

If you just want to list one part of the Git configuration, such as *alias*, *core*, *remote*, etc., you could just pipe the result through grep. Something like:

```
git config --global -l | grep core
```

Answer (score 5):

To find all configurations, you just write this command:

```
git config --list
```

In my local i run this command .

```
Md Masud@DESKTOP-3HTSDV8 MINGW64 ~
$ git config --list
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
rebase.autosquash=true
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
http.sslbackend=openssl
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
credential.helper=manager
user.email=infomasud@gmail.com
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
```

Comment: The git config command is a convenience function that is used to set Git configuration values on a global or local project level. These configuration levels correspond to .gitconfig text files.  Read More here :  https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/git-config

Comment: Great, can you add that to your answer?

Answer (score 4):

On Linux-based systems you can view/edit a configuration file by

```
vi/vim/nano .git/config
```

Make sure you are inside the Git init folder.

If you want to work with `--global config`, it's

```
vi/vim/nano .gitconfig
```

on /home/userName

This should help with editing: https://help.github.com/categories/setup/

Answer (score 2):

In Windows to edit global config run From **git bash** (but not from general command prompt)

```
notepad ~/.gitconfig
```

Location of files are listed in https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Where-system-global-and-local-Windows-Git-config-files-are-saved [image]