# Save/Fix Pull checked/unchecked options on TortoiseGit

Tags: git, user-interface, tortoisegit, pull

How do I save/fix some checked/unchecked options on the pull dialog of TortoiseGit? Some people from my team want to use this tool and if they don't uncheck the options highlighted the current branch is force-merged and the HEAD gets lost every time.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand "current branch is forced merged and the HEAD get lost every time". Can you clearify?

Comment: Yes @MrTux, for some reason the TortoiseGit override the master HEAD (forcing, not merging or rebasing) therefore the local master looses the HEAD reference from the origin one.

Comment: Sorry, still don't understand.

Comment: I guess this link https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References can help you @MrTux

Answer (score 1):

The highlighted checkboxes are so-called three-state-checkboxes. In the highlighted form those are in the indeterminated state, i.e., TortoiseGit does not explicitly activate or deactivate those options, but uses the default of Git.

TortoiseGit uses the three-state checkboxes here, so that you can override the default which is configured in vanilla git (there are several ways in git for configuring this, e.g. `fetch.prune`, `remote.<name>.prune` and maybe others).

In order to change the default you have to use [git config](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).

For controlling the default value of prune see `fetch.prune` and `remote.<name>.prune`. For controlling the value of tags see `remote.<name>.tagOpt`.

Comment: Is a fresh and new repo with anything configured so far, could you give me the attributes to me explicitly disable them?

Comment: In order to see current values, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12254105/3906760. I can't give you exact attributes as there are many possible ones as I described in the answer.