# git - set KDiff3 as default mergetool

Tags: git, kdiff3, mergetool, git-difftool

After installing `KDiff3` for managing conflicts in `git`, still the default one is opening for me:

[image]

Here is the configuration that mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33348841/4055329):

```
git config --global --add merge.tool kdiff3
git config --global --add mergetool.kdiff3.path "C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe"
git config --global --add mergetool.kdiff3.trustExitCode false

git config --global --add diff.guitool kdiff3
git config --global --add difftool.kdiff3.path "C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe"
git config --global --add difftool.kdiff3.trustExitCode false
```

**NOTE:** I can be able to run `KDiff3` individually with simple files, but I can't run it in my git project. Any idea?

**Edit:** Here is my .gitconfig :

```
[user]
    email = vahid.vdn@gmail.com
    name = vahid najafi
[diff]
    tool = kdiff3
    guitool = kdiff3
[merge]
    tool = diffmerge
    tool = kdiff3
    tool = kdiff3
[mergetool "diffmerge"]
    trustExitCode = true
[mergetool "kdiff3"]
    path = C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
    trustExitCode = false
[difftool "kdiff3"]
    path = C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
    trustExitCode = false
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I configure KDiff3 as a merge tool and diff tool for git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308482/how-can-i-configure-kdiff3-as-a-merge-tool-and-diff-tool-for-git)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I made another solution! I used `meld` instead of `kdiff3`. First download [meld](http://meldmerge.org/) from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/meld-installer/). Then change config for `meld` in c:/Users/yourName/.gitconfig :

```
[user]
    email = vahid.vdn@gmail.com
    name = vahid najafi
[diff]
    tool = meld
[difftool "meld"]
    path = C:/Program Files (x86)/Meld/meld/meld.exe
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[merge]
    tool = meld
[mergetool "meld"]
    path = C:/Program Files (x86)/Meld/meld/meld.exe
[mergetool]
    keepBackup = false
```

**NOTE:** Try to use git `cmd` instead of windows `cmd`. When you have conflict, just run : `git mergetool`. For more detail and example, see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Qynj8WUwgs).

Comment: Expect the
[answer for KDiff3](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/kdiff3/kdiff3/git.html)
to be very similar to your answer here.
~ * ~
An advantage of using Git *Bash* instead of Git cmd is that the commands will be the same (often identical) as those on Linux and macOS.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know `kdiff3`, but you might need to add the files you want to compare to your tool call as parameters (see command line options for KDiff3 call [here](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/doc/documentation.html#id2488370)). In your global config (accessible via `git config --global -e`), the respective lines should look something like this:

```
[merge]
    tool = kdiff3
[mergetool "kdiff3"]
    trustExitCode = false
    cmd = 'C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe' "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"
```

Since I did not try this with KDiff3, you might have to switch the order of `"$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$REMOTE"`and `"$MERGED"` variables, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133290/git-merging-using-meld) post sould provide enough additional more information on this. Although it's about the Meld tool, I'm pretty sure the handling is analogical, and there are some pretty good and informative answers.

EDIT: 
Assuming you use windows: You can just locate it in Windows explorer, usually in `c:\user\yourusername\.gitconfig`, and open it with any editor. In Linux, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12254076/how-do-i-edit-my-global-git-config). Then, replace all the `merge`, `mergetool`and `difftool` sections with the following:

```
[merge]
    tool = kdiff3
[mergetool "kdiff3"]
    cmd = "C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe" "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"
    trustExitCode = false
[difftool "kdiff3"]
    cmd = "C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe" "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"
    trustExitCode = false
```

If ot does not work, it is possible that you have to change the order of `"$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$REMOTE"`and `"$MERGED"` variables or remove one of them. You can find sufficient information about this in the links provided above.

Comment: Thanks. I run `git config --global -e` , but this part doesn't exist: `"$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"`

Comment: Yes, I expected as much. You should add it to make sure KDiff3 is called with the right files.

Comment: How should I add? As I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: You can either run `git config --global difftool.kdiff3.cmd"C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe" "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED" ` from command line, setting the value in your config file, or edit the whole config file directly. `git config --global -e` opens the config file in the default editor (using git for windows, this would be `vim`). I would edit the whole file directly, since you can make sure there are no leftovers from all the command line editing.

Comment: I run the command you mentioned, but nothing is changed. I added my `.gitconfig` file to the question. How can I add it manually?

Comment: Now I get this error: `/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-mergetool--lib: line 124: C:/Program: No such file or directory
fatal: external diff died, stopping at index.php` .

Comment: I even installed `meld`. It works fine when running `git difftool origin/master` , but when running `git mergetool` again it lead me to default mergetool in cmd.

Comment: I was working on windows `cmd`. So migrated to git `cmd`. It solved the problem with `meld`. Anyway, thanks for paying attention.

Comment: In my case, I had to add the -o arg before the "$MERGED", so my config line has to be:
cmd = "C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe" "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$REMOTE" -o "$MERGED"