# Using git difftool to compare current branch to other branch commit

Tags: git, git-diff, git-difftool

Current git branch I'm using is X.

I Would like to use installed difftool (in my case, kdiff3) in order to diff X against branch Y-specific commit.

e.g. `git difftool branch_X..branch_Y$commit_hash --tool=kdiff3`

What is the correct syntax to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Per [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-difftool.html), it would be `git difftool --tool=kdiff3 branch_X $commit_hash`.

Comment: Thanks, If you could post as an answer i'll accept it

Comment: And extending it to diff a specific file ? :)

Comment: @Adiel: `git difftool` takes the same arguments as git diff : `git difftool A B -- file1 file2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git - set KDiff3 as default mergetool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611783/git-set-kdiff3-as-default-mergetool)

Comment: kowsky, how is my question is a duplicate? I didn't ask how to use kdiff3 by default