# Git branch command behaves like 'less'

Tags: git, terminal, git-branch, pager

When I use the `git branch` command to list all branches, I see the output of `git branch | less`.

The command `git branch` is supposed to show a list of branches, like `ls` does for files.

This is the output I get:

[image: git branch paging output]

How do I get the default behaviour of `git branch`? What causes the paged output?

My `.gitconfig` looks like this:

```ini
[user]
  email = myemail@mail.com
  name = Dennis H.
[push]
  default = simple
[merge]
   tool = vimdiff
[core]
  editor = nvim
  excludesfile = /Users/dennish/.gitignore_global
[color]
  ui = true
[alias]
  br = branch
  ci = commit -v
  cam = commit -am
  co = checkout
  df = diff
  st = status
  sa = stash
  mt = mergetool
  cp = cherry-pick
  pl = pull --rebase
[difftool "sourcetree"]
  cmd = opendiff \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
[mergetool "sourcetree"]
  cmd = /Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/opendiff-w.sh 
  \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" -ancestor \"$BASE\" -merge \"$MERGED\"
  trustExitCode = true
```

Answer (score 1361, accepted):

As mentioned in [comments to Mark Adelsberger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48341920/git-branch-command-behaves-like-less#comment83670608_48342309), this was a default behavior change [introduced in Git 2.16](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.16.0.txt#L85-L88).

You can turn paged output for `git branch` back off by default with the [`pager.branch` config setting](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-pagerltcmdgt):

```sh
git config --global pager.branch false
```

Comment: That is an odd, odd decision to make default. I expect my unix-y cli tools to behave like dumb simple programs that you can chain if you want to, but I guess that discussion is for another site.

Comment: @Stragulus Note that the new default doesn’t stop you from chaining `git branch` with something else. Using [pipe detection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/911168/578288), Git will output the branch list to stdout within the commands `git branch > branches.txt` or `git branch | wc -l`.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane but with pager, I have a type an extra `ESC/q` after a simple `git branch` check.

Comment: @mitnk Not necessarily. If your pager is `less`, you can add `--no-init --quit-if-one-screen` to your `LESS` environment variable, which will cause `less` to just write to stdout if the text can be viewed without scrolling. See [`man less`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/less) for more details.

Comment: If you want to add it into your config file manually, it's `[pager]
 branch = false` (on two lines).

Comment: @Sam's tip works the same for paginated results for `git diff`, `git stash` etc. for anybody having this issue with those commands. Just add any variation of `stash = false` under a header of `[pager]` in your .gitconfig file.

Comment: I use the following command to list remote branches using a pattern `git branch --list "*" -r | tr -d " *"`

Comment: In response to @RoryO'Kane's comment, you may want to do `export LESS = "--no-init --quit-if-one-screen -R"` (with -R) in your .zshrc, .bash_profile, etc., to honor raw color control characters.  Otherwise, your git log will suffer.

Comment: Setting `git config --global pager.branch 'less --quit-if-one-screen -R'` with a version of less >= 530 works great!

Comment: `git config --global core.pager ''` Will turn of the pager on all git commands

Comment: Are you really sure? The behaviour shows up only under zsh, but not bash. I happen to have both shells installed.

Comment: I hate when default behavior is changed leaving you to figure out how to revert it, and specifically I hate this behavior of git branch :/

Comment: Works also with tag subcommand: `git config --global pager.tag false`.

Comment: Some of the other answers give a reason as to why this behaviour differs between zsh and bash, and a better solution too (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60498979/1836776)

Comment: You can do the same with any subcommand of git; see [git config documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pagerltcmdgt) for `pager.<cmd>`.  So to turn off paging for the log command, you would use `git config --global pager.log false`.

Comment: `git config --global pager "less -FX"` shows the pager only when the content is larger than the screen. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14118014/171318

Answer (score 115):

As other answers pointed out, Git defaults to piping itself into a pager (`less` by default) for most commands.

An important point, though, is that [when the LESS environment variable is unset, Git sets it to FRX](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-corepager), and the consequence is that the user-visible behavior is the same as if the pager was not used when the command's output is short (i.e. if you have only few branches). See [man less](https://linux.die.net/man/1/less):

> -F or --quit-if-one-screen 
>      Causes less to automatically exit if the entire file can be displayed on the first screen.
>
> -R or --RAW-CONTROL-CHARS 
>       [...]ANSI "color" escape sequences are output in "raw" form.
>
> -X or --no-init 
>       Disables sending the termcap initialization and deinitialization strings to the terminal. This is sometimes desirable if the
>   deinitialization string does something unnecessary, like clearing the
>   screen.

If you get the behavior you describe, you most likely have `$LESS` set to something else, and unsetting it (`unset LESS`) would get rid of the issue while keeping the "pager" behavior for long output. Alternatively, you can activate the behavior for while keeping `$LESS` as-is by adding this to your `.gitconfig` file:

```
[core]
    pager = less -FRX
```

If you really dislike the pager thing, you can deactivate it globally or on a per-command basis (see other answers).

Comment: I had `pager = less -FR` as the option `X` seems to be disabling the mouse scrolling.

Comment: One liner `git config --global core.pager "less -FRX"`

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect: Keeping it simple for small outputs, while still having the benefits of a pager where needed

Answer (score 104):

Not to argue semantics, but the behavior you're getting *is* the default. That's why you get it when you don't ask for something different. By default, `branch` (and numerous other Git commands) use a pager when sending output to the terminal.

You can override this default by using the `--no-pager` option:

```
git --no-pager branch
```

Or if you redirect the output to a file, Git should detect that it isn't writing to a terminal and so should not use a pager anyway.  (On the other hand, that suggests a scripting use case, in which case you should consider using a plumbing command like `git for-each-ref` in preference to `git branch`.)

Comment: `git --no-pager branch` works. But how is this set? Only the `PAGER` environment variable is set to `less`.
This is not the default behaviour. All of my colleges have an output as a list printed out to the terminal.

Comment: Which version of git are you using? And which one are your colleagues using?

Comment: 2.16.0! Is this a feature introduced to git in this version?

Comment: Yeah it is default now.
https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.16.0.txt#L85

My college next to me using the same version and does not have this issue :) thx @mark

Comment: See my answer: it's not really the default. If you (or your distro) did not set `$LESS`, you get a different behavior because Git sets it for you.

Comment: This is the most superior answer here, sad that it has so few upvotes, because I scrolled quite a bit to find this masterpiece.

Comment: Are you really sure? The behaviour shows up only under zsh, but not bash. I happen to have both shells installed.

Comment: `git --no-pager branch` seems best to me, so it helps you to remember the `--no-pager` option and can do both easily. When looking at remotes e.g. with `git branch -a`, the list of branches can easily fill the screen, so paging is preferable, but when looking at your local branches, there often won't be so many, and you may want to list them on the command line so that you can remind yourself what branches you have and then do e.g. `git checkout <branch-name>`.

Comment: This answer works and It doesn't need to modify my environment

Comment: This answer is very useful because it leaves the config defaults as they are but allows changing the behavior for specific cases.

Comment: Added this to my alias like: `br = !git --no-pager branch`
Works like I want it now.
Edit: An answer below already did it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54128018/6367600

Answer (score 104):

The accepted answer seems wrong. There are two problems:

1. The behaviour is actually different between (default configured) bash and zsh. The ‘problem’ shows up only under zsh.
2. The suggested solution will make `git branch` not use a pager always, which will not be desired when there is a lot of output.

The real reason is that bash and zsh have different default definitions about LESS: bash defines nothing, while zsh defines it to `-R`. When I do `unset LESS` in zsh, everything goes back to normal....

The `-R` behaviour may still be desired. In that case, you can add the following instruction to your .zshrc to keep everything working:

```sh
export LESS=-FRX
```

`-F` ‘causes less to automatically exit if the entire file can be displayed on the first screen’. However, `-X` needs to be specified simultaneously, otherwise no output will be shown when there is less than a screenful of output.

Comment: This isn't true -- the behaviour shows up under most Linux variants when the LESS environment variable is set. zsh isn't special in this regard (or any other).

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer What is not true? I said exactly that what mattered was whether LESS was set: ‘bash defines nothing, while zsh defines it to `-R`. When I do `unset LESS` in zsh, everything goes back to normal....’ As to whether this happens, it is that defaultly-configured bash does not define LESS, while defaultly-configured oh-my-zsh defines LESS. I know this because I had exactly the same oh-my-zsh environment in macOS (just like the asker), and I encountered exactly the same problem.

Comment: In 1, you said that the behaviour only shows up in zsh. As I said, that's not true. The env var is set to -R in  my ubuntu-bash too, so not just zsh. In 2, you implied that outputting to sdtout is not desirable when there is lots of output; also wrong. In my automated environments, paging is *never* desirable, no matter the length of the results. Given that automation is a large portion of operations these days I'd say that the stdout behaviour is highly desirable in a lot of cases, and 'maybe' less so for manual diagnostics and legacy work. So, this is wrong. The original answer is right.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer You completely failed to notice that the original question was asked about the behaviour under macOS (other systems, of course, may have different default behaviour). Take a closer look at the paths. — Your comment about the automated environments does not make sense as well, because paging is only enabled automatically in a TTY, but not when the output is redirected.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Doing cmd+f in the VSCode terminal to search for branch names wasn't working for me but adding `export LESS=-FRX` in my .zshrc fixed it!

Comment: can confirm `-X` flag being required to get `-F` to work properly in zsh/Big Sur

Comment: after adding this answer to `.zshrc` file, I also need to run `source .zshrc` in terminal to make it works. thank you very much

Comment: @Alexa289 Sourcing the .zshrc file should be automatic on all new sessions. It does not affect terminal sessions that are already started, though.

Answer (score 71):

This Git behaviour was more and more annoying for me, too.
I got my tag list in `less` when just wanting to list tags for example.

One can control this behaviour also by changing the default ***Git PAGER*** to `cat` instead of `less`. I'd rather scroll in iTerm than in an editor. I like to use the editor when I want.

So:

```sh
git config --global core.pager cat
```

Comment: thanks for the heads-up. I admit after a couple of months usage, I am still using cat, but for example when doing `git log` it is annoying. I just miss the original behaviour, but did not have time to improve my daily workflow in this pespective.

Comment: There is yet another solution that binds features from both words: `cat` and `less`: it's [`bat`](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat) *A cat(1) clone with wings*. A tiny summary: for short output (fits on one screen) it behaves like `cat`, and like `less` for long outputs (to large output for one screen). To me, it's *almost* a perfrect solution.

Comment: This would be ideal.
Interesting, did not know about `bat`, it's not on my mac bin, I see there's a link to the github bat project. I'll have a look. Thx.

Comment: actually you can decide which things are paged and which not. I absolutely want my git log being paged, but not the tag list (or the branches...) See the accepted answer

Comment: This is the best answer for me coming from terminal to iterm.

Answer (score 16):

For those that want to update their `~/.gitconfig` to fix this, it would look like this:

```
[pager]
   branch = false
```

Comment: strange thing here: this setting was working and since some days it's not anymore, did anything change or Is my config just not being applied?

Comment: @ConquerorsHaki This solution is working for me with git v2.17.1  Try `git config --list --show-origin` to debug what settings are/aren't set for you/your system and from where (https://stackoverflow.com/q/12254076/1590950).

Answer (score 5):

Do the following:

```
[alias]
  br = !git --no-pager branch
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just see your branches (unformatted) you can pipe git branch to cat with:

```
git branch | cat
```

Answer (score 0):

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables

> GIT_PAGER controls the program used to display multi-page output on
>   the command line. If this is unset, PAGER will be used as a fallback.

To solve your issue, you could unset PAGER and GIT_PAGER in your shell.

Comment: Unset `PAGER` (`GIT_PAGER` was unset) issue is still there. Are there any location I have to check this env vars?

Comment: @DenniJensen You can set the pager on the command like `PAGER= git branch` (with one space after and none before the equals sign exactly like written). No idea, whether it's any better than e.g., `git branch | cat`.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me (Powershell under Windows)

```
$ git branch | echo
```