# How do I output git branch command result to standard out by default?

Tags: git

How do I get the command `git branch` to display its output to standard output directly instead of displaying it in a less editor?

I want to be able to do this

```
$ git branch
* develop
  master
```

Instead of typing the command (1) and see the output in a less editor (2):

(1)

```
$ git branch
```

(2)

```
* develop
  master
(END)
```

I don't want to type `git branch | cat` every time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git branch command behaves like 'less'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48341920/git-branch-command-behaves-like-less)

Comment: Create an alias that uses cat

Comment: Technically, less is a pager, rather than an editor, but: `git --no-pager`, or set environment variable `GIT_PAGER`, or configure `core.pager`, or configure `pager.branch` to `false`, etc. (Note that the default behavior used to be the equivalent of having `pager.branch` set to `false`, so that's the accepted answer in the linked duplicate.)

Comment: Can't find the linked answer when I'm about to post this question, got what I want, thanks for the comments!