# git branch -v always stucks the cmd

Tags: git, git-branch

[image]

Like this screenshot shows, after I typed `git branch -v` and typed Enter, the cmd will always be stucked.I have tried to make another new clone, but this problem didn't disappear.

It happens to my every repository, and I have tried upgrade / reinstall my git.
Maybe there are some weird software conflicts exists

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48370253/7976758 ? Try `git --no-pager branch -v`

Comment: Do not post images of code, input/output data or error message. Use the select and copy-paste functionalities provided by the operating system and post the text as text in the question. Put a line that contains only `\`\`\`` before it and another one after it or indent it with 4 spaces to be rendered nicely.

Comment: Related to the suggestion of @phd, what happens if you press `q`? Or if you press `Ctrl-C`? (when you run the command without `--no-pager`)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems caused by a malware. This malware is forced to be installed at where I work. It is a network access control software, but it seems more than that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this phenomenon is due to windows, try it under wsl/wsl2

Comment: ...Very sad, this problem can be produced in wsl too.