# My integrated vscode terminal (zsh) opens git cli when I type in "git branch"

Tags: visual-studio-code, oh-my-zsh

I just installed the Oh my zsh terminal plugin in Mac OS and
Everytime I type in `git branch` on my zsh terminal in VS code, it opens the git cli. how do I fix this?

When I type in `git branch`
[image]

It changes to the git cli
[image]

I have to ctrl + z out of this to go back to zsh:
[image]

I am expecting a similar behavior to bash where typing in `git branch` produces the following:
[image]

Comment: Did you find a fix to it?

Answer (score 3):

This article helped me and fixed the issue you're seeing!
[Git branch command behaves like 'less'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48341920/git-branch-command-behaves-like-less)

tl;dr - you want to update your config using

```
git config --global pager.branch false
```

Comment: works when using vim as [core] editor too.