# git branch displays my branch names in a VIM window, instead of in my current iterm2 window

Tags: git, git-branch

Not sure why this is happening.

I use iterm2, and have .zshrc bash

When I run `git branch`

It displays my branches "in a new window" is there a way to fix this?

[image]

My config:

```
alias projects="cd ~/Projects"


# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=~/.node/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="/Users/lgaban/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set name of the theme to load --- if set to "random", it will
# load a random theme each time oh-my-zsh is loaded, in which case,
# to know which specific one was loaded, run: echo $RANDOM_THEME
# See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"

# Set list of themes to pick from when loading at random
# Setting this variable when ZSH_THEME=random will cause zsh to load
# a theme from this variable instead of looking in $ZSH/themes/
# If set to an empty array, this variable will have no effect.
# ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=( "robbyrussell" "agnoster" )

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion.
# Case-sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks.
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to automatically update without prompting.
# DISABLE_UPDATE_PROMPT="true"

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13

# Uncomment the following line if pasting URLs and other text is messed up.
# DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# Caution: this setting can cause issues with multiline prompts (zsh 5.7.1 and newer seem to work)
# See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/5765
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# You can set one of the optional three formats:
# "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# or set a custom format using the strftime function format specifications,
# see 'man strftime' for details.
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load?
# Standard plugins can be found in $ZSH/plugins/
# Custom plugins may be added to $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(git)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# User configuration

# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"
```

Comment: When you say *in a new window*, do you mean that your current iterm2 display *clears*, shows you the above, and then when you type `q` to exit `less`, the old display *comes back* leaving no trace of the `git branch` output?

Comment: Note that this clear-the-display effect is due to the (IMO unfortunate and in-need-of-destruction) *alternate screen* option that the terminfo for iterm2 uses. Adding `-X` to your LESS options will prevent `less` from invoking the alternate screen setup and teardown. This doesn't fix *other* programs that still have the alt-screen effect, and terminfo makes it hard to correct; a good xterm/iterm/terminal-emulator should have a "disable alt screen" checkbox, IMO, but a lot don't.

Comment: You probably also want the `-F` and `-R` options set. Whether you want `-S` set is more personal taste. Export `LESS=FRX` or `LESS=FRSX` in your `.zshrc` to set these.

Comment: @torek that was it! Thanks!!! Want to post your answer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not actually a *new* window, and it is not vim either: it is `less`, which is the default pager on a lot of systems including yours.  The `git branch` command uses the pager by default now (as of Git 2.16); see in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48370253/1256452) to [Git branch command behaves like 'less'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48341920/1256452).

There is a further bad interaction here, worthy of note, that affects those who use `zsh` but not those who use `bash`, at least with many of the various defaults that are included with these shells.  Explaining what is going on requires a bit of background, though the standard fix is easy to list:

```
 export LESS=FRX
```

in your `.zshrc` (note: some people prefer `FRSX`).

#### Background

In the old days of ["glass ttys"](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/G/glass-tty.html) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal)), there was just *the screen*.  If you cleared The Screen, it was clear.  If you wrote text to it, it had that text.  These things were just emulating printers, without using paper.  But they acquired new capabilities, such as highlighted or bold or underlined text, fancy cursor-addressing systems, and so on.

Some terminals required special "enable cursor motion" setup operations before they could do fancy screen drawing.  (It's not really clear why: did they think someone would start cursor-addressing mode by mistake?  But they did.)  So early software for *using* this stuff had a feature: it would send an "initialize" sequence.

One small subset of terminals grew an *alternate screen*.  The [VT100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) and follow-ons used an escape sequence, <kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>?</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd>, to enter Alternate Screen mode, and the same but ending with lowercase L (`l`) instead of `h`, to exit it.  The Alternate Screen was literally that: switching to it got you a different screen, and switching back put your old screen contents back.

As windowing systems became commonplace, [*terminal emulators*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) running on [*pseudo-terminals*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal) took place of the old "glass ttys".  You could open lots of new windows and have lots of individual mini-screens.  Each one could emulate some favorite existing physical terminal, such as the VT100 or VT220.  These particular escape sequences were even standardized (ANSI X3.64, ISO/IEC 6429), with various extensions.

These became `xterm`, which, in Biblical terms, begat (at least indirectly) iTerm and iTerm2 and others.  Alas, *someone* got it into their heads that this was a good idea in the *initialization* of an xterm, into cursor-positioning screen-editor mode, that this should include the "switch to alternate screen" sequence.  Exiting this mode switches back.  The result is that your editor session doesn't disturb any ongoing command session—which some find nice, I guess—but the *additional consequence* of this decision is that when `less` sends this same initialization sequence, this *also* flips to the alternate screen.  The escape sequence is sometimes slightly different now,<sup>1</sup> but it's the same underlying problem.

As far as I am concerned, this entire thing is a horrible idea in the first place (see also [this superuser.com question](https://superuser.com/q/134598/941003) and [this web site](https://www.shallowsky.com/linux/noaltscreen.html)).  If you can completely kill off the alternate screen—as you can in xterm—that's the ultimate cure.  Alas, these days you often can't.  An alternative I use is to modify the termcap or terminfo to remove the alt-screen escape sequences.  This is a bit tricky on many systems.

---

<sup>1</sup>I have no idea why.  If anyone does know, that might make interesting lore.

---

#### This brings us to `less` and Git

The `less` *program* has its own cure for the alternate-screen blues: the `-X` command line option tells `less` *do not emit the initialization sequence*.  This is a pretty big hammer, but it works fine.

Git has a compiled-in default pager, set by whoever builds your Git distribution.  The usual default is `less`.

To make `less` itself convenient to use, `less` reads the [*environment variable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) `LESS` at startup.  Any options set here are applied by default unless you override them on the command line.  So you can set `F`, `R`, `S`, and/or `X`—all of which are commonly-desirable options—in `$LESS` and `less` will use those settings.

Git will, if `LESS` is *not* set in the environment, *automatically* set it to `FRX`.  Again, [this is actually a compiled-in default](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e0a2f5cbc585657e757385ad918f167f519cfb96/Makefile#L1954-L1956), but the "default default" is `LESS=FRX LV=-c`.  (`LV` is for the [`lv` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lv).)

Curiously, some standard zshrc, distributed *with* zsh, apparently does an `export LESS=R`.  This means that `LESS` now *is* set in the environment, and Git carefully does *not* disturb it: Git assumes that you *meant* to have it set this way.  When you switch to bash and your bashrc does *not* set `LESS`, Git sets it for you; when you switch to zsh and your zshrc *does* set `LESS`, Git does not override it.

The cure, then, is to set (and export) the `LESS` settings you want, assuming you will continue using `less`.  Note that you can configure your pager in Git itself, using `GIT_PAGER` or `core.pager`; see [the top level `git` command documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git).  You can set options there too; these will override the `LESS` settings.  For instance, you could set `core.pager` to `less -FRSX` to get those four options just in Git, while leaving `$LESS` set to, say, just `R`, to get just that one option when you run `less` yourself.

Here's what the four options *mean:*

- `F`: short for `--quit-if-one-screen`, this makes `less` exit immediately, without displaying `(END)` or similar.  This is quite useful with short `git branch` output.
- `R`: short for `--RAW_CONTROL_CHARS`, this makes `less` recognize ANSI color escape sequences so that `git branch` can show the *current* branch in green, for instance, or show colored `git diff` output.
- `S`: short for `--chop-long-lines`, this makes `less` truncate long lines, requiring "sideways scrolling".  `S` really stands for Side Scroll, at least in my own head.  The default, without `-S`, is to wrap long lines, so that no sideways scrolling is required.<sup>1</sup>
- `X`: short for `--no-init`, this inhibits the initialize (and final de-initialize) sequences, which in iTerm2 are what is making your `git branch` output disappear when you exit the pager.

Note that you can disable Git's pager entirely, and use your terminal's scroll-back, if you prefer that.

---

<sup>1</sup>I *almost* like the `S` setting myself, except for one flaw: there's no indication that a long line got truncated and that scrolling is required.  So someone can, e.g., hide a secret message by putting it way off to the right of each line.  In practice, this means that some `git diff` output tends to get cut off sometimes, and however rare it is, it's *just* annoying enough to keep me from setting `-S` most of the time.

There's a secret here though: you can, while *inside `less` itself*, turn these options on and off!  If you have long lines wrapped and it would be nice to have side scrolling on now, just turn that on.  Type <kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> and press <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> at the colon prompt to toggle the setting off and on.

Answer (score 6):

I can get very similar results with `LESS= git branch`. say `git help config` and look through the `/pager` results, also the various (git-specific and non-) environment variables that control pager behavior, the environment git and the pager it invokes are running in make the pager give the full behavior even on short results.

The simplest option that tells Git to always use the options it normally supplies only when you *haven't* got a default is

```
git config core.pager 'less -FRX'
```

and you can control this with more granularity if you like, see the docs.

Comment: Thanks! A comment on my original question was it `export LESS=FRX` Torek or you can add this and I can accept :)

Comment: This is a better answer considering it won't change the behavior of LESS, if used by the developer somehow.