# Mac(m1 chipset) Terminal Problem : everything looks like vim editor

Tags: vim, terminal

Once I used sudo vim   to write and save a hidden file(like .gitignore).

after that, I happened to use `git log`, and the result is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVJ47.png)

Nothing else appears in the terminal, no scroll allowed.

And the second:
I ran `git branch -r`, and the result is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztOCk.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NldtJ.png): when I scrolled terminal screen.

This looks quite like vim editor, like the only way to 'END' that is typing 'q'.

and the Third:
I used `brew update`, but terminal doesn't show any progress on the screen and
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrVLt.png)
all the progress was showing on this bar.

How can I rollback my terminal to normal? Same thing happens in VScode also.

Comment: It's not `vim`, it's a pager called [`less`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/less). You can scroll it left/right/up/down, search, etc. Press `q` to exit.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [pager](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144016/what-is-a-pager) called `less`. As [phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd) answered in the comments, you can quit out of it with `q`.  The `branch` option for the `git` command can be reset to not use the pager:

```
git config --global pager.branch false
```

This is popular because a lot of people don't like that behavior for `git branch`, and it's actually a question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48341920/git-branch-command-behaves-like-less).

Note, confusing the two (`vim` and `less`) is common. It's understandable because there are a lot of navigation keys in common between `vim` and `less`, as well as many other tools in Unix.  This is one reason why learning vim is hard but so very useful.  Some examples:

```
j k u d e y q space 50% gg G /
```

Two cheatsheets with several of these common commands:
[vim](https://gist.github.com/awidegreen/3854277)
[less](https://gist.github.com/glnds/8862214)