# SSH Permission Denied and Different Fingerprint Generated in Terminal compared to in Gitlab SSH Key

Tags: windows, git, gitlab, ssh-keys, openssh

Currently I am facing a problem with git clone a repo using SSH. I had set up my SSH Key and inserted it into GitLab. However still it does not work out.

Permission denied as like below:
[image]

And another problem is the fingerprint generated above is different from the one that is generated in Gitlab as shown below:
[image]

Hope if anyone could help. Had been troubleshooting this for a few days.

I tried to delete the .ssh folder and regenerate new key and did everything the same again but turn out to be the same, Permission denied and fingerprint is never matching.

I am using OpenSSH and OS: Windows 11 for this problem. I had also tried `ssh -Tvvv <username@server>` , `ssh <username@server>`, `ssh -Tv <username@server>` to verify whether if I am connected but the same permission denied.

Comment: I believe you are mistaking fingerprint of your SSH key for authenticating (that's what the Gitlab shows) and the fingerprint of the Gitlab server's hostkey (that's the console output shows). => Though that does not explain why you cannot authenticate. Just do not get misled by the fingerprints. + Please, post the console output as a text, not as an image.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, the server fingerprint (for the ~/.ssh/known_hosts) differs from the public key fingerprint.

For the latter, test it with `ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com`, and check your private key is used.

If your private key does not have a default name (like `id_rsa`), you would need a `~/.ssh/config` to reference your key.

```
Host gl
  Hostname gitlab.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myKey
```

And `ssh -Tv gl` for testing.

Comment: Hi @VonC I have followed your steps and there is a whole output on the console. It seems fine but there is an output that I find weird

`debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\yapch/.ssh/config`
`debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling`


Still I can't clone the repo using ssh because of Permission Denied. Hope you could help. Thank youu

Comment: @YapWeiCheng Try and *not* use OpenSSH, but the SSH packaged with Git for Windows. Set your PATH in a CMD (for testing) as [I suggest here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75433297/6309) and see if it works better. Are you behind a VPN? Are you using a proxy?

Comment: Okay i will avoid using OpenSSH. Yes I am using a VPN to connect to the Gitlab server. Do I need to configure the VPN of something?

Comment: @YapWeiCheng I my experience, egress SSH connection is not always allowed through VPN. I am using a VPN and only uses HTTPS URL for GitLab, because SSH is blocked.